# What am I doing wrong? Prepared statement login

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, prepared-statement

This is my login.php files, when the form directs to this page to run the code, the screen **says**

> "this page is not working"

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it? Also, when I have got the code to work, the cookies have not been set, which makes me think that the error is around there.

```
//IF REMEMBER ME IS TURNED ON
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=? AND password=?");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $SearchEmail, $SearchPassword);

// set parameters and execute
$SearchEmail = $email;
$SearchPassword = $password;
$stmt->execute();
if($stmt->fetch() == true) {
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        setcookie("SIT_name", $row['FirstName'], time()+3600*24*365*10, '/');
        setcookie("SIT_acc_type", $row['acc_type'], time()+3600*24*365*10, '/');
    }

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET last_log=? WHERE email=? AND password=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $time, $SearchEmail, $SearchPassword);
    $time = 'Time: '.date("h:i:sa").', Date: '.date("d/m/Y").'.';
    $SearchEmail = $email;
    $SearchPassword = $password;
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        echo "Success";
        //Header('Location: ../');
    }
} else {
    echo "Wrong Username or Password!";
}
```

**Screenshot** (from comment section)
[image]

Comment: @MuthaFury If you look at the screenshot, you will see the message which appears when I try to run the code in the question; http://prntscr.com/bh1nce

Comment: @MuthaFury Also, when I have got the code to work, the cookies have not been set, which makes me think that the error is around there.

Comment: From the error, it seems like a PHP error. Can you try check the error log see what causes the problem?

Comment: @MuthaFury No error log has been created, that is the first thing I tried to look for.

Comment: Try putting `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: @MuthaFury Nope, still getting the 'The ______ page is not working" message.

Comment: @MuthaFury could the error be around this part:

`if($stmt->fetch() == true) {
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {`

As when I remove this, it works fine.

Comment: @MuthaFury I got the PHP errors showing and it says: `Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in ______ on line 21`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours of messing around with the code, I have figured out a fix, it's not the best but it'll do as I don't have time (I'm 16 and currently doing my GCSEs).
The working code is as follows:

```
//IF REMEMBER ME IS TURNED ON
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT FirstName, acc_type FROM users WHERE email=? AND password=?");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $email, $password);

// set parameters and execute
$email = $OrigEmail;
$password = $OrigPassword;

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($FirstName, $acc_type);
$stmt->store_result();

if ($stmt->num_rows == 0) 
{
    Header('Location: ../?err=1');

    $stmt->close();

    return 0;
}
else
{
    $FirstNames = array();
    $acc_types = array();

    while($stmt->fetch())
    {
        $FirstNames[] = $FirstName;
        $acc_types[] = $acc_type;

    }
    print $FirstNames[0];

    setcookie("FirstName", $FirstNames[0], time()+3600*24*365*10, '/');
    setcookie("SIT_acc_type", $acc_type[0], time()+3600*24*365*10, '/');

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET last_log=? WHERE email=? AND password=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $time, $SearchEmail, $SearchPassword);
    $time = 'Time: '.date("h:i:sa").', Date: '.date("d/m/Y").'.';
    $SearchEmail = $OrigEmail;
    $SearchPassword = $OrigPassword;
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        //echo "Success";
        Header('Location: ../?suc=1');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
//IF REMEMBER ME IS TURNED ON
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=? AND password=?");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $SearchEmail, $SearchPassword);

// set parameters and execute
$SearchEmail = $email;
$SearchPassword = $password;
$stmt->execute();

if($stmt->fetch() == true) {
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
        setcookie("SIT_name", $row['FirstName'], time()+3600*24*365*10, '/');
        setcookie("SIT_acc_type", $row['acc_type'], time()+3600*24*365*10, '/');
    }

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET last_log=? WHERE email=? AND password=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $time, $SearchEmail, $SearchPassword);
    $time = 'Time: '.date("h:i:sa").', Date: '.date("d/m/Y").'.';
    $SearchEmail = $email;
    $SearchPassword = $password;
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        echo "Success";
        //Header('Location: ../');
    }
} else {
    echo "Wrong Username or Password!";
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this still doesn't work. I read somewhere that it could be due to me calling `$stmt->fetch()` (or similar) multiple times, if so, what can /should I do?

Comment: I've just had a play and changed the while loop to be this: `if($stmt->fetch() == true) {
     $result = $stmt->fetch();
     setcookie("SIT_name", $result['FirstName'], time()+3600*24*365*10, '/');
     setcookie("SIT_acc_type", $result['acc_type'], time()+3600*24*365*10, '/');`
this code now prints 'success' but does not set the cookies.